# CSS: equal border around 3 images (different sizes) dynamically generated

Tags: html, css

I have a div that get 3 spans with images in them. The images are often different sizes, images are dynamically selected.

```
<div id="main" style="display: block;">
 <span id="1"><img src="url1" style="max-width:30%"></span>
 <span id="2"><img src="url2" style="max-width:30%"></span>
 <span id="3"><img src="url3" style="max-width:30%"></span>
</div>
```

The image fit width wise. What I am looking for is equal borders around the different size images.

Have tried: .main span {border: solid 5px gray; height: 100%;} and many other options.

On a computer, the 3 images would be side by side. On a phone the images would be on top of each other. And all with equal borders.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the HTML *and* the CSS you now have, in a snippet.

Comment: Show an image/drowing of how you want them on mobile.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to place the images on top of each other on the phone *and* side by side on computer.

Do not use inline-styles, because they will overwrite your style sheet.

Does this suit your needs?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  /* subtract border and padding from element's width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main .image-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main .image-list>span {
  display: block;
  /*add 4px (2 x 2px) space between photos */
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: streach;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main span.border {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main span.border img {
  /*replace with width: 100% if you want to force the image to full width */
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


/* Desktop break-point */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #main .image-list > span {
    width: 33.333%;
    padding: 0 2px;
  }
  #main .image-list>span:nth-child(3n) {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  #main .image-list>span:nth-child(4n+1) {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #main span.border {
    border: 5px solid gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="image-list">
    <span id="1">
      <span class="border"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?gravity=east"></span>
    </span>
    <span id="2">
      <span class="border">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600?gravity=west">
      </span>
    </span>
    <span id="3">
      <span class="border">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?gravity=south">
      </span>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's more like this I found on the web: [link](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/art_friesen_stylewebcss3/elementLinks/figure2.jpg) No matter the size of the 3 images that are most likely: display: inline-flex or flex. The borders are all the same.

Comment: When the images are side by side (computer web browser mode), I think you have it right. It but it isn't the same up and down (phone mode), rectangles would be best but squares are okay. The end goal is for the user to select one of the images to be used in a post. The span borders will turn red on selection. So, the spans and images need to dynamically change. Image the spans as button to be clicked on. Got you guys with a hard one? :)

Comment: @7huan Show an image/drowing of how you want them on mobile.